# Problem with drawing canvas line in scrollView

Tags: java, android, canvas, scrollview

I'm trying to draw a scrollable timeline. I implement singleLine custom view for drawing a line between circle ImageView's of recycler view:

```
public class SingleLine extends View {
    WeakReference<Context> ctx;
    Paint paint;
    PointF pointA, pointB;
    private int height_custom;

    public SingleLine(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ctx = new WeakReference<>(context);
        init();
    }

    public SingleLine(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ctx = new WeakReference<>(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        pointA = new PointF();
        pointB = new PointF();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setColor(ctx.get().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(pointA.x, pointA.y, pointB.x, pointB.y, paint);
        invalidate();
    }

    public PointF getPointA() {return pointA;}

    public void setPointA(PointF pointA) {this.pointA = pointA;}

    public PointF getPointB() {return pointB;}

    public void setPointB(PointF pointB) {this.pointB = pointB;}
}
```

And in onBindViewHolder() method of my adapter, I use an interface for measuring x/y coordinates of first and last visible view of recyclerview:

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TaskViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Tasks tasks = datalist_tasks.get(position);
    String hour = "" + tasks.getHour() + ":" + tasks.getMinute();
    holder.tv_clock.setText(hour);
    holder.tv_title.setText(tasks.getTitle());
    holder.tv_comment.setText(tasks.getComment());

    holder.itemView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                holder.itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            else
                holder.itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            if (iOnMeasureCustomView != null)
                iOnMeasureCustomView.onMeasure(holder.iv_status, position);
        }
    });
}
```

And I implement that interface in my activity like below:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(_C.get(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
rv_tasks.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);
tasksAdapter.setiOnMeasureCustomView(new IOnMeasureCustomView() {
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(ImageView iv_status, int position) {
        int[] screen = new int[2];
        iv_status.getLocationOnScreen(screen);
        int width = (int) ((iv_status.getWidth() / 2) + convertDpToPixel(8));
        if (position == layoutManager1.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()) {
            pointA.set(iv_status.getX() + width, iv_status.getY() + convertDpToPixel(8));
        } 
        else if (position == layoutManager1.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()) {
            pointB.set(iv_status.getX() + width, screen[1] - convertDpToPixel(40));
            singleLine.setPointA(pointA);
            singleLine.setPointB(pointB);        
            singleLine.invalidate();
        }
    }
});
```

And also I implement addOnScrollListener() for my recyclerview and write this code snippet (I don't know that if this implementation is correct or no):

```
rv_tasks.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
         PointF a = singleLine.getPointA();
         PointF b = singleLine.getPointB();
         if (dy > 0) {
            a.y -= dy;
            b.y -= dy;
            singleLine.setPointA(a);
            singleLine.setPointB(b);
            singleLine.invalidate();
        } else {
            a.y += Math.abs(dy);
            b.y += Math.abs(dy);
            singleLine.setPointA(a);
            singleLine.setPointB(b);
            singleLine.invalidate();
        }
    }
});
```

My problem is when I scroll in activity, like the gif below, my singleLine is something like cutting off imageView and the end x/y of line become the x/y of end of the screen.

[image]

[image]

**Questios**

1. How can I set x/y of the line to prevent this?
2. And also I need some help with drawing this line with animation. How can I draw this line with animation that starts when the activity started?